# ASP.NET: After deploy, my own ThreadPool threads are not terminated and CPU is 100% utilized

Tags: asp.net, iis, appdomain, producer-consumer, blockingcollection

I have a ASP.NET application running on IIS 7, .NET 4 which occasionally needs to talk to another web service (fire and forget style notifications). Up until now I used to fire a `Thread` for each single notification which I find quite noneffective (due to high cost of creating a new thread).

For that reason I started to employ the `BlockingCollection<>` container to keep track of the notifications which need to be processed and at `Application_Start` I use this code to start 3 consumers to process this queue:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(Consumer.Create(sessionBuilder), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
Task.Factory.StartNew(Consumer.Create(sessionBuilder), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
Task.Factory.StartNew(Consumer.Create(sessionBuilder), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Where sessionBuilder is just an object providing database sessions.

The consumer looks like this:

```
public static class Consumer
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Consumer));

    public static Action Create(ISessionBuilder sessionBuilder)
    {
        return () =>
        {                
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (RequestQueue.Requests.IsCompleted)
                        return;                        

                    var request = RequestQueue.Requests.Take();
                    Process(sessionBuilder, request);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    log.Error("Exception caught in the consumer's thread", e);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    // The processing methods
    //
}
```

While this seems to work fine, as soon as I deploy new version of my application to IIS, the server's CPU starts being 99% utilized with my `w3wp` process. This definitely comes with my using BlockingQueue, it did not use to be this way before the change.

Trying to figure out where exactly is the CPU time spent, I got [WMemoryProfiler](http://wmemoryprofiler.codeplex.com/) and WinDbg to see a capture of all managed threads' stack traces in any moment.

In this way I found out that in the moment of CPU being 100% utilized by my process, I have 17 consumer threads running and all of them spending their time with the following:

```
[GCFrame: 0000000012b2df58]
[HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 0000000012b2e048] System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait(Boolean, Int32, System.Object)
System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeout(Int32, Int64, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].TryTakeWithNoTimeValidation(System.__Canon ByRef, Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource)
System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].TryTake(System.__Canon ByRef, Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Take()
AppServer.Core.Queue.Consumer+<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)
[GCFrame: 0000000012b2eae8]
[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 0000000012b2eed0]
[ContextTransitionFrame: 0000000012b2f068]
[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 0000000012b2f290]
```

So, obviously, I have an issue here. The consumers are not being terminated upon the AppDomain unload (which occurs as soon as first HTTP request arrives after the deploy).

---

1) Why aren't the consumers terminated? I thought that's what `AppDomainUnloadException` is for.

2) Should I have some global cancellation token which I would signal (but when?) and let the current consumers know their time is over? Or what is the recommended pattern here?

3) Is it normal that 17 threads spending their time in the call stack shown above fully utilize the CPU? Or, rather, is it normal that calling `Take()` on `BlockingCollection<>` can put so many threads simultaneously to this situation?